# Heap block at .. modified at .. past requested size of

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory

I try to create a window in another window with Qt and delete the first window. When the second window is opened the first window is deleted but when I try to delete the second window I get this error:

> HEAP[Flash-TestBench-Client-Rev1-0.exe]: 
>   Heap block at 18FBC298 modified at 18FBC2C4 past requested size of 24

Here is my simplified code:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ConnectionWindow *w = new ConnectionWindow;

    return a.exec();
}
```

connectionwindow.cpp

```
ConnectionWindow::ConnectionWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *w = new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setText("Connect");
    conenect(button, SINGNAL(pressed()), this, (openW()));

    l->addWidget(button);
    w->setLayout(l);

    this->setCentralWidget(w);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    this->show;
}

void ConnectionWindow::openW(){
    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;

    this->close;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *w = new QWidget;

    QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    button->setText("Close");
    conenect(button, SINGNAL(pressed()), this, (closeW));

    l->addWidget(button);
    w->setLayout(l);

    this->setCentralWidget(w);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    this->show;
}

void MainWindow::closeW(){  
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: it seems like you are missing some `()` in the MainWindow `this->show;` and same with connectionwindow and `this->close;`

Comment: The code you posted cannot be compiled. Please provide your actual code.